# Search using multiple fields Django (building the object list)

Tags: django, search, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have recently rolled out a simple search into a Django application I am working on. The search filters an index of the following model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    task_description  = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

And is implemented as follows:

View:

```
def ViewAllTasks(request):

    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        tasks_list = task.objects.filter(task_name__contains=q)
    else:
        tasks_list = task.objects.all().order_by("task_name")
```

Template/HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
        <form action="/tasks" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Currently this searches on the Task name and returns all the tasks if nothing is searched on. However, I would like to expand the search to also search across description and category and am having trouble trying to define a filter on multiple objects. I have tried everything including the following:

```
tasks_list = task.objects.filter(~Q(task_name__contains=q) + ~Q(task_description__contains=q) + ~Q(category__contains=q))
```

I would like to catch the overlap here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the + use |

If you want you get the list where the the task_name, task_description and category **doesn't contains** q (q being case **sensitive**)

```
tasks_list = Task.objects.filter(~Q(task_name__contains=q) | ~Q(task_description__contains=q) | ~Q(category__contains=q))
```

If you want you get the list where the the task_name, task_description and category **doesn't contains** q (q being case insensitive)

```
tasks_list = Task.objects.filter(~Q(task_name__icontains=q) | ~Q(task_description__icontains=q) | ~Q(category__icontains=q))
```

If you want you get the list where the the task_name, task_description and category **contains** q (q being case **sensitive**)

```
tasks_list = Task.objects.filter(Q(task_name__contains=q) | Q(task_description__contains=q) | Q(category__contains=q))
```

If you want you get the list where the the task_name, task_description and category **contains** q (q being case **insensitive**)

```
tasks_list = Task.objects.filter(Q(task_name__icontains=q) | Q(task_description__icontains=q) | Q(category__icontains=q))
```

| is used for OR

& is used for AND

Comment: What a great answer! Thanks!